# Vertica unique constraint with nullable columns

Tags: vertica

I have a table with a unique constraint, where `a`, `b` and `c` are all nullable:

```
ALTER TABLE public.t1 ADD CONSTRAINT unique_ids UNIQUE (a, b, c);
```

Then I inserted two records, deliberately leaving `b` as null :

```
insert into t1 (a,c) values ('test', '12312'); 
insert into t1 (a,c) values ('test', '12312');
```

I expect that the unique constraint has been violated, but apparently Vertica doesn't think so because the following returns nothing:

```
SELECT ANALYZE_CONSTRAINTS('t1');
```

How can I enforce a unique constraint across multiple (nullable) columns in Vertica?

Comment: Why are you analyzing constraints on a the 'partner_installs' table? You need to analyze constraints on the 't1' table because that is the table which has the constraint violations.

Comment: fixed the table name thx for the catching that.

Answer (score 2):

I'd have to consult the documentation for a final answer, but I'm pretty sure that Vertica doesn't enforce constraints during an insert. It has to do with optimizations.

I always enforced uniqueness in my ETL framework if I required it.

Also, if I was doing a large amounts of aggregations as my output, I didn't worry about a few dupes here and there. Maybe that's bad form, but a few entries out of billions didn't worry me.

Comment: He's doing 2 inserts, and then running the analyze_constraints(). So what you said is true, but mtrbean should already be aware of it? He'd be happy with detecting violations post-insert, I think, which analyze_constraints isn't doing for him.

That said, we also avoid using Vertica's constraint checking as a way of doing uniques. We rely on our processing to produce unique inputs.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I'm aware that the constraint is not enforced during insert. The documentation doesn't mention anything about the behavior when the columns are nullable.